# Injected services undefined for cron job

Tags: node.js, cron, nestjs

Trying to run a cron job at 12 am each day, however, services being called during the job are undefined.

When calling the endpoint the logic works just fine, it just fails when the cron task runs the code. All of my injected services are undefined.

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'deleteAllDailyReviews' of undefined`

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAllUsers' of undefined`

I've tried to bind `this` to the task, however, the problem still persists.

- Nest version: 6.5.3
- Node version: 10.16.0
- Platform:  Windows

Cron job:

```js
import { UserService } from '../user/services/user.service';
import { UserWordService } from '../user/services/user-word.service';
import { schedule, ScheduleOptions, ScheduledTask } from 'node-cron';
import moment from 'moment';
import { parseExpression } from 'cron-parser';
import { ReviewService } from '../review/review.service';

@Injectable()
export class UtilitiesService {


    private options: ScheduleOptions = {
        scheduled: false
    };
    private task: ScheduledTask;

    constructor (
        private readonly userService: UserService,
        private readonly userWordService: UserWordService,
        private readonly reviewService: ReviewService,
    ) {
        this.task = schedule(environment.cronnJobExpression
            , this.executeCronJob.bind(this)
            , this.options);

    }

    public startJob() {
        this.task.start();
    }

    public async executeCronJob () {
        const format = 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss';
        console.info(`Starting cron job at: ${moment().format(format)}`);

        try {
            await this.reviewService.deleteAllDailyReviews();
        } catch (e) {
            console.info(`updateAllWords failed \n`, e);
        }
        let users: any;
        try {
            users = await this.userService.getAllUsers();
        } catch (e) {
            console.info(`getAllUsers failed \n`, e);
        }

        if (users) {
            //
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

Module declaration:

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    //
    UtilitiesModule,
   //
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(
    private readonly utilitiesService: UtilitiesService
  ) {
    this.utilitiesService.startJob();
  }
}
```

All methods from injected service should be defined and run. The logic is sound when calling the executeCronJob method from a controller, just not during the cron job.

Comment: Sounds like this is somehow not correctly bound. Can you try running `() => this.executeCronJob()` instead? Or running it in `onModuleInit` instead of the `constructor`.

Comment: I moved the task definition into the `startJob` method and it was working on development, but once it went to production?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the task definition to `startJob` method did it for me. Thanks to Kim Kern for the help.

```
public startJob() {
   this.task = schedule(
       environment.cronnJobExpression,
       this.executeCronJob.bind(this),
       this.options);

   this.task.start();
}
```